# The extreme dS black holes in 5 dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401192, we have a $f(r)$ in Eq(6).
$$f(r)=1-(\Lambda/3)r^2-M/r^{(D-3)}+Q^2/r^{2D-6}$$
In 5 dimension $f(r)$ is
$$f(r)=1-(\Lambda/3)r^2-M/r^2+Q^2/r^{4}$$
For the extreme dS black holes, this equation rewrote as Eq(10)
$$f(r)=-(\Lambda/(3r^4))(r-\rho)^2(r+\rho)^2(r^2-3/\Lambda+2\rho^2)$$.
I do not how the Equation (10) is obtained? Could you please help me?

Comment: This post would benefit from more context. Can you explain the article you are citing in more detail?

Comment: Sure, In 5 dimension $M=r_{+}^{2}+r_{-}^{2}$ and $Q^2=(r_{+}r_{-})^{2}$, then I replaced $M$and $Q^2$ in $f(r)=1−(\Lambda/3)r^{2}−M/r^{2}+Q^{2}/r^{4}$. After that, for exteme ds blackhole  , I replaced $r_{+}=r_{-}=\rho$. But  I could not to get $f(r)=−(\Lambda/(3 r^4))(r−\rho)^{2}(r+\rho)^{2}(r^2−3/ \Lambda+2ρ^2)$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what this paper is about. But you can check Eq(10) is just Eq(6) as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(r) &= -\frac{\Lambda}{3r^4}(r-\rho)^2(r+\rho)^2(r^2-\frac{3}{\Lambda}+2\rho^2)\\
&=-\frac{\Lambda}{3r^4}(r^4-2r^2\rho^2+\rho^4)\cdot(r^2-\frac{3}{\Lambda}+2\rho^2)\\
&=-\frac{\Lambda}{3r^4}(r^6-\frac{3r^4}{\Lambda}+2\rho^2r^4-2\rho^2r^4+\frac{6r^2\rho^2}{\Lambda}-4r^2\rho^4+r^2\rho^4-\frac{3\rho^4}{\Lambda}+2\rho^6)\\
&=-\frac{\Lambda}{3r^4}(r^6-\frac{3r^4}{\Lambda}+\frac{6r^2\rho^2}{\Lambda}-3r^2\rho^4-\frac{3\rho^4}{\Lambda}+2\rho^6)\\
&=-\frac{\Lambda}{3r^4}(r^6-\frac{3r^4}{\Lambda}+\frac{3r^2}{\Lambda}\cdot\rho^2(2-\Lambda\rho^2)-\frac{3\rho^4}{\Lambda}(1-\frac{2\Lambda\rho^2}{3}))\\
&=1-\frac{\Lambda}{3}r^2-\frac{\rho^2(2-\Lambda\rho^2)}{r^2}+\frac{1-\frac{2\Lambda\rho^2}{3}}{r^4}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
M &= \rho^2(2-\Lambda\rho^2)\\
Q^2 &= 1-\frac{2\Lambda\rho^2}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$
then we can get Eq(6).

Comment: Thank you so much. It is right but I want to know how can I get from Eq(6):$f(r)=1−(\Lambda/3)r^{2}−M/r^{2}+Q^{2}/r^{4}$ to Eq(10):$f(r)=−(\Lambda/(3 r^4))(r−\rho)^{2}(r+\rho)^{2}(r^2−3/ \Lambda+2ρ^2)$

Comment: The paper says $M=\rho^2(2-\Lambda\rho^2)$ and $Q^2=1-\frac{2\Lambda\rho^2}{3}$ below the Eq(10) in the paragraph "Thus, besides the degenerate horizon ...". So if you adopt the expressions of $M$ and $Q^2$, you can just get Eq(10) from Eq(6) from the opposite direction in the post.